# Get the location of a class element in the class array from hovering or clicking the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently making a project where I have different characters and as you hover over each of them information is displayed about them. While I may be able to get passed this problem with IDs, I was wondering if there was any way to obtain the location of an object in a class using given information (like using indexOf).

```
<div class="people"> 
<div>Steve</div>
<div>James</div>
<div>Mike</div>`
</div>

<div class="peopleInfo">
<div>Likes pizza</div>
<div>Is a very good chef</div>
<div>Has a family to look after</div>
</div>
```

The text in .peopleInfo is hidden and appears when I hover over each person(I have that part sorted out). Each is synced up chronologically with each person (i.e Steve Likes Pizza).
Is there a way that I could get the index of Steve in .people by hovering over him, in order to produce the text "Likes pizza"?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript code that you have tried?

Comment: All of the JavaScript I had tried seemed to have failed, so I saw no point in adding it.

Comment: You should always post the code that you've tried because it lets us better understand what you are attempting. And, your attempt may be on the right track, but only require us to fix some small items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(() => {
  const people = $('.people div').toArray();
  const peopleInfo = $('.peopleInfo div').toArray();

  $('.people').on('mouseenter', 'div', ({target}) => {
    const info = peopleInfo[people.indexOf(target)];
    
    console.log(target.textContent, info.textContent);
  });
});
```

```css
.peopleInfo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="people">
  <div>Steve</div>
  <div>James</div>
  <div>Mike</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="peopleInfo">
  <div>Likes pizza</div>
  <div>Is a very good chef</div>
  <div>Has a family to look after</div>
</div>
```